# "ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED" error when using the pkg tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, canvas, vercel

I am attempting to package my Node.js application including canvas package using the pkg tool to create an executable. However, I am running into the following error:Error: error: 126C: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED' at process.dlopen (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:2251:28)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Reproduce the steps explained in the link here after to recreate the nodejs app
  https://www.section.io/engineering-education/compile-your-nodejs-application-into-a-exe-file/
- Add the canvas package
- import the canvas package in your index file
- Run the following command: node index.js then pkg index.js and .\index-win.exe
- Observe the mentioned error.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expected the pkg command to generate a working executable without encountering any "ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED" errors.

**Actual Behavior:**

The pkg command fails with the mentioned error, making it difficult to generate a functional executable.

**Environment**

Node.js Version: Node.js v16.17.0, 18.5.0 and 18.17.0
Operating System: windows 10
pkg Version: pkg v5.8.1

**Additional Context**

This issue occurs consistently. The exe file generated without canvas works correctly.

**Screenshots :**

package.json

[image: package.json]

Error message
[image: error message]

Comment: Internets suggest removing `node_modules` and then doing `npm i` to get a fresh modules tree. Maybe make sure your current source tree is backed up first.

Comment: @Pointy Hello and thanks for your help. I did it several times but it do not change any thing.

Comment: Well it looks like something isn't finding a component file during a `require()` somewhere, which is why rebuilding the module tree didn't seem like a crazy idea.

Comment: I just make a npm rebuild and it doesn't change anything. Is that what you mean when you said "rebuilding the module tree" ? If no, what did you mean

Comment: like it says in my comment, remove `node_modules` and then do `npm i`

Comment: @Pointy. I just remove node_modules then I reinstall but it didn't change any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the solution from somebody in Github. The solution was to separate the pkg config json file from the package.json file.

pkg.json :

```
{
    "name": "hellocanvas",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Canvas sample",
    "pkg": {
        "assets": [
            "node_modules/canvas/build/Release/**/*"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "node18-win-x64"
        ],
        "outputPath": "dist"
    }
}
```

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "hellocanvas",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "bin": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "make-exe": "pkg -c pkg.json index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "canvas": "^2.11.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "pkg": "^5.8.1"
    }
}
```

then to generate the exe file with the command :

```
npm run make-exe
```